# CASE expression in SQL throws ORA-00905

Tags: oracle, case, cognos

I have the below code in Cognos. When I validate it throws ORA-00905.

```sql
SELECT 
(CASE WHEN #prompt('prompt_name','string',"'A'")# = 'A' then ABC = 'S'
ELSE ABC END)
FROM table_name;
```

Thanks for the help!!!

Comment: What is "then ABC = 'S'?

Comment: ABC is a field name in my query. I didn't give the exact field name here,.. so am assigning ABC = 'S'

Comment: Just remove the assignment and keep 'S' because in certain condition you want ABC to show 'S' irrespective of what value it has in db and else it will display actual value.

Comment: You use equality sign inside WHEN clause to check if condition is true of false  inside THEN you will simple asisgn a value to column and dont need assignment operator for that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to use assignment here `ABC = 'S'`. Your query must look like this:

```
SELECT 
    (CASE 
        WHEN #prompt('prompt_name','string',"'A'")# = 'A' then 'S'
        ELSE ABC 
    END)
FROM table_name;
```